# Linear congruency

Tags: linear-algebra

please I need some help here... (dont understand the answer) it's a  task on congruency. I have the feeling that at the end something went worng. is it possible to have a negative solvation? Thank you!I have exams coming up. So help would be amazing!I am a bit stuck with my solvation. And I would appreciate to know what I did wrong..

Solve the linear congruency

$$15x = 3 \mod 47$$

My solvation is:

$$\frac{47}{18x} -3$$
$$47y= 18x -3$$
$$3=18x- 47y$$
$$\gcd(18,47)$$
$$47= 2 \cdot  18 +11$$
$$18=1 \cdot 11+7$$
$$11=1 \cdot 7+4$$
$$7=1 \cdot 4+3$$
$$4=3 \cdot 1+0$$

$$\gcd(18,47) =1$$

now looking for $x$ by turning the terms round until it comes to the form.

$$3= 18x - 47 y$$
$$1= 4- 3 \cdot 1$$
$$1=4-(7-1 \cdot 4)$$
$$1=2 \cdot 4- 1 \cdot 7$$
$$1=2 \cdot (11-1 \cdot 7)-1 \cdot 7$$
$$1=2 \cdot 11-3 \cdot 7$$
$$1=2 \cdot 11-3(18-1 \cdot 11)$$
$$1=5 \cdot 11-3 \cdot 18$$
$$1=5 \cdot (47-2 \cdot 18)-3 \cdot 18$$
$$1=5 \cdot 47-13 \cdot 18$$
$$1=235-234    \mid \cdot 3$$
$$3= -39  \cdot 18 + 15  \cdot 47$$
$$L= \{[-39]47\}$$

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you wrote. Please do write down your mathematics with LaTeX. You can find directions in the FAQ section.

Comment: Besides all the written stuff so far, one can sinply check whether the assumed solution is *actually* a solution: substitute in the original equation. You'll see at once that $\,-39=8\pmod{47}\,$ is **not** a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$5\cdot 19=95=1\pmod{47}\Longrightarrow 5^{-1}=19$$

$$3\cdot 16=48=1\pmod {47}\Longrightarrow 3^{-1}=16$$

thus

$$15^{-1}=(3\cdot 5)^{-1}=19\cdot 16=(16\cdot 3)\cdot 6+16=1\cdot 6+16=22$$

so that finally

$$15x=3\pmod{47}\Longrightarrow x=15^{-1}\cdot3=22\cdot 3=19\pmod{47}$$

The above shows the general way many of these exercises can be solved. Now, in this particular case, a much simpler, shorter and faster way to the solution is possible:

$$15x=3\Longleftrightarrow 3\cdot 5x=3\Longrightarrow 5x=1\Longrightarrow x=5^{-1}=19$$

Comment: Hey Antonio,Thanks for your answer. I must admit I don´t really understand it.. Sorry I am just studying primary school education. How do you find the numbers, 19, 16..?? just by change?

Comment: and maybe do you see that my mistake is above??

Comment: Until you don't write down that with LaTeX I don't even try to read it, @Sophia

Comment: i it better to see for you now? thanks!

Comment: No @Sophia, sorry. Read my comment under your question, please.

Comment: sorry i can not handle with the computer so good to download this programme... can anyone else understand my solvation??please

Comment: You don't need any program, @Sophia.Go and read directly here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117

Comment: Thank you antonio,I found the mistake. I have to add 47 again. because the solutions need to be between 0 and 47-1. so if I add 47 to -39, I have found the solution :-) Thanks for your effort!!

Comment: I'm not sure that solves your mistake(s), @Sophia: from the beginning, you have $\,\frac{47}{18x}-3\,$...what is this? This isn't even an equation, and where does that $\,18x\,$ come from?